# Room getting ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I am facing an issue while inserting data to Android table. Here is my Dao functions:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(freight: Foo)

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(freights: MutableList<Foo>)
```

Here is how it is invoke:

```
  Observable.fromCallable {
          db.fooDao().insert(it)
       }
    }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe {
                Logger.d("Inserted ${it} users from API in DB...")
            }
```

Exception I am getting:

```
   Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
    at com.blockgrain.blockgrain.dbmanager.repository.FooRepository$insertDataInDb$1.call(FooRepository.kt:76)
```

I have created other tables with same logic they are working fine but this one is failing . Please let me know what went wrong.

**Update** :

Foo.kt

```
 override fun get(): Observable<MutableList<Foo>> {
    val observable = getDataFromDb()
    return observable.flatMap {
        if (it.isEmpty())
            getDataFromApi()
        else
            observable
    }
}

override fun getDataFromApi(): Observable<MutableList<Foo>> {

    return WebService.createWithAuth().getFooFromWeb()
            .doOnNext {
                Logger.d(" Dispatching ${it} users from API...")
                Observable.fromCallable {
                     db.fooDao().insert(it)
                      }
                  }
                  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                  .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                  .subscribe {
                           Logger.d("Inserted ${it} users from API in DB...")
                  }
               }
}
```

Comment: Which method you are calling here `db.fooDao().insert(it)` for single element or for list of `Foo` ?

Comment: I tried both with single and list.. both fail with same exception

Comment: Are you sure you are not modifying the list same time you are accessing it?. And can you share code for `FooRepository.kt:76`

Comment: Added code for FooRepository.. Exception is at 

    db.fooDao().insert(it)

Comment: are you trying to insert multiple items with this code?

Comment: I have tried single and multiple both

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the given code, It is **not directly clear** how the array list modification is being called resulting into `Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` .
My guess is, multiple operations are being performed on same list at a time.

Your insert list method in dao is accepting `MutableList<Foo>` change it to `List<Foo>` as Room doesn't need mutable list. like this,

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(freights: List<Foo>)
```

I would recommend to **copy the array list** to **another list** before doing any operations on the list like this

```
// Before performing any operation on list
var newList:List<Foo> = ArrayList<Foo>(otherList)
// Perform operation on newList - for ex.
db.insert(newList)
```

There is another solution for `ArrayList` if you want to use it concurrently with [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). But this will result into significant modification in existing in code. So I would recommend to go with first option.

Comment: This worked but I am still confused where the list is being used on other hand.. Thanks anyway..

Comment: Glad it helped. You may need to debug your code to find where its getting used concurrently as code is reactive we cannot determine it directly